# Compiling flex project on Maven error without information

Tags: apache-flex, maven, livecycle, flexmojos

Since 2 days ago, i can't compile my flex project.

I tried it in 3 different computers and via eclipse and command-line and all I have is an error without information

If I run it in debug mode (-X) and error mode (-e), only get this.

This is the only error code I have:

```
[ERROR] -1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error compiling!

[DEBUG] Trace

    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error compiling!
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error compiling!
        at org.sonatype.flexmojos.compiler.AbstractFlexCompilerMojo.build(AbstractFlexCompilerMojo.java:2450)
        at org.sonatype.flexmojos.compiler.AbstractFlexCompilerMojo.run(AbstractFlexCompilerMojo.java:1275)
        at org.sonatype.flexmojos.AbstractIrvinMojo.execute(AbstractIrvinMojo.java:176)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
```

I'm blocked :(

This is the flexmojos configuration

```
<groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
<artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.5.0</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
```

It's a multi-project but in this case is a child project that i'm trying to compile

In this 2 days, we've only made small changes in code but everything was ok after that because we need to compile and package a new version after each issue.

Comment: Can you provide any more information?  You said "Since 2 days ago"...does that mean that it _used to_ work and now it doesn't?  How is your Maven project structured?  Do you have a multi-module project?  Did you use Flexmojos plugin to set up the project?  What version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: I've added information you requested

Comment: Finally i've solved it. I checked all mxml files and it changed only 1 byte each one. I revert to last version and it worked fine.